# SwiftUI: Lock subview position when orientation changes

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm building a custom camera in SwiftUI as part of my app and I'm trying to achieve a similar experience as with the native camera: when the device rotates, only the zoom labels and the thumbnail rotate. The shutter and the rest of the controls stay in the same position. They don't go to the bottom of the screen when in landscape mode.

So far I've only found approaches to lock **the entire screen** to a certain orientation, but that's not what I want.

Is that possible to achieve in SwiftUI at all?

Thanks a lot.